# Can a Fighter, with Battle Master Archetype, multiclass with Fighter Champion?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing

I have a 9th level fighter with Battle Master Archetype. Can I multiclass and take another level of Fighter but to advance in Champion this time as an Archetype?